# Ошибка запроса к серверу Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

недавно прошел краткий курс ноды, для написания дипломного проека в универе.
Столкнулся с огромным количеством различных ошибок при написании подобия сервера. Сейчас уже загнан в тупик и не могу решить проблему, прошу помощи.

**Код моего сервера**

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
const app = express();
const port = 8080;




const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {

 const db = client.db('diplom');
 const collection = db.collection('lessons');

 if (err) throw err;
 console.log('Connection established');
 collection.find().toArray((err, results) => {
                 
        console.log(results);
        client.close();
    });
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.get('/admin', (res) => {
 const datag = {
  "name": "Вася",
  "age": 35,
  "isAdmin": false,
  "friends": [0, 1, 2, 3]
 }
 /* res.writeHead(200, {'ContentType': 'text/html'}); */
 res.send(datag);
 res.write('fuck')
 res.end();
});

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log('Server is up and running on port ' + port)
});
```

**Код запроса к серверу**

```js
let header = new Headers({
   /*  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', */
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
});

let myInit = { method: 'GET',
               mode: 'cors',
      header: header, 
   };

const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/admin';

function Request () {
 fetch(endpoint, myInit)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((res) => {
     console.log(res);
  })
}


export default Request;
```

**Ошибки**

[image: consoleLogMyErr]

Comment: а сервер у Вас работает? К MongoDB подключается?

Comment: Так точно. Если в res.send послать строку, то отображает. Да и к базе пробовал запросы делать, текст получал. Прошу прощения что не включил эти данные в описание проблемы.

Comment: Попробуйте сериализовать datag перед отправкой

Comment: как отписаливыше  сериализовать JSON.stringify(datag)